# How to make a div expand to right side of page and bottom of page

Tags: css

I need to create a div that has its top left corner aligned with the top left corner of its parent div, its right side aligned with the right edge of the page, and the bottom side aligned with the bottom of the page.  Does anyone know how this can be done with CSS?

Comment: I don't believe this can be accomplished using CSS alone, since the inner div will not be able to know where the right or bottom sides of the screen are from within its context.

Comment: You need JS for that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `<div>` itself?

You could achieve something like this with `vh` and `vw` units if you position absolute the parent too;

```
div.parent{
  position: absolute;
   top: 10vh;
   left: 10vw;
}

div.child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90vw; // Remainder of viewport width
  height: 90vh; // Remainder of viewport height
}
```

This will make the `div.child` be aligned to the left of the `div.parent`, but stretching the length and height of the browser.

IF you want this to be something that is calculated, you'll ideally want to use javascript/jQuery.